sparse-checkout: Too long compared to the full clone
I'm trying to configure a sparse checkout with partial clone of my repo to reduce drastically my git configuration time at the start of a job in my GitLab CI.
I tried on one job and it seems to work, because I included only the folder that contains my scripts, and I have had an huge reduction of times (60mins to 5, ora 40mins to 8secs, based on job).
Now, I'm trying to do the same including only some folders with binary files I need, but it seems doesn't work, because doing a complete checkout take about 1 hour, and using my sparse checkout take about 3 hours... Can someone help me with this?
I tried this two ways to do it:
.config-sparse-checkout-test: &config-sparse-checkout-test
  stage: config_sparse_checkout
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
    DEFAULT_SPARSE_CHECKOUT_DIRS: "Scripts"
  before_script:
    - echo 'Starting Branch:' $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    - mkdir -p $CI_PROJECT_DIR
    - cd $CI_PROJECT_DIR
    - git clone --filter=blob:none --sparse $CI_REPOSITORY_URL .
    - SPARSE_CHECKOUT_DIRS=${OVERRIDE_SPARSE_CHECKOUT_DIRS:-$DEFAULT_SPARSE_CHECKOUT_DIRS}
    - git sparse-checkout set --cone --depth=$GIT_DEPTH --sparse-index $SPARSE_CHECKOUT_DIRS
    - echo "Sparse checkout completed for directories:\ $SPARSE_CHECKOUT_DIRS"    - apt-get update && apt-get install -y tree
    - echo "Current working tree:"
    - tree

sparse-test:
  stage: test
  extends: .config-sparse-checkout-test
  image: my_image:latest
  tags:
    - docker
  variables:
    GIT_DEPTH: "1"
    OVERRIDE_SPARSE_CHECKOUT_DIRS: >-
      Scripts
      Folder 1/Folder 1_1
      Folder 2/Folder 2_1/Folder 2_2
      Folder 3/Folder 3_1/Folder 3_2
  script:
    echo "Test Completed"
  rules:
    - if: '$TEST1 == "true"'



.config-sparse-checkout-test2: &config-sparse-checkout-test2
  stage: config_sparse_checkout
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
    GIT_DEPTH: "1"
    DEFAULT_SPARSE_CHECKOUT_DIRS: "Scripts"
  before_script:
    - echo 'Starting Branch:' $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    - mkdir -p $CI_PROJECT_DIR
    - cd $CI_PROJECT_DIR
    - git clone --filter=blob:none --sparse $CI_REPOSITORY_URL .
    - git sparse-checkout init --no-cone
    - SPARSE_CHECKOUT_DIRS=${OVERRIDE_SPARSE_CHECKOUT_DIRS:-$DEFAULT_SPARSE_CHECKOUT_DIRS}
    - echo "$SPARSE_CHECKOUT_DIRS" | tr ' ' '\n' > .git/info/sparse-checkout
    - echo "!*.meta" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
    - git sparse-checkout reapply
    - echo "Sparse checkout completed for directories:$SPARSE_CHECKOUT_DIRS"
    - apt-get update && apt-get install -y tree
    - echo "Current working tree:"
    - tree

sparse-test2:
  stage: test
  extends: .config-sparse-checkout-test2
  image: my_image:latest
  tags:
    - docker
  variables:
    OVERRIDE_SPARSE_CHECKOUT_DIRS: >-
      Scripts
      Folder 1/Folder 1_1
      Folder 2/Folder 2_1/Folder 2_2
      Folder 3/Folder 3_1/Folder 3_2
  script:
    - echo "Test Completed"
  rules:
    - if: '$TEST == "true"'

I expect performing a sparse-checkout and partial clone of the repository to be faster than performing a full clone/chechout.
